# .NET core 1.1 and localization in runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

In an application I am developing there is a demand for output messages to be localized.
I my web api project I have succeed it with the globalization/localization features of .net core. Each user has a specific locale in the database, so with a custom RequestCultureProvider I have managed to access user's principal, grab his language and alter RequestCultureProvider.
But sometimes I run procedures which send push notifications messages to users. For example:

```
    foreach(var user in users) 
        await SendNotification("message", user.DeviceId)
```

If I rewrite like: *await SendNotification(localizer["message"], user.DeviceId)* then each user will have the same translation of "message". Is it possible to change in runtime the localizer according to user.cultureInfo?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can.

You just need to call the localizer with `.WithCulture(...)`

```
foreach(var user in users)
    await SendNotification(localizer.WithCulture(new Culture("en-US"))["message"], user.DeviceId)
```

Of course replacing the `en-US` with a variable or property which contains the culture, i.e.

```
foreach(var user in users)
    await SendNotification(localizer.WithCulture(new Culture(user.CultureInfo))["message"], user.DeviceId)
```